# Can't install libudev-dev on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I cant seem to find a solution for installing libudev-dev package.
It outputs this error

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    libudev-dev : Depends: libudev1 (= 229-4ubuntu4) but 229-4ubuntu5 is to be installed

So i tried
sudo apt-get install libudev1

> libudev1 is already the newest version (229-4ubuntu5).

You may have notice that in my machine a latest version of it is installed. which is 229-4ubuntu5
I also tried what was suggested here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181073/ubuntu-12-04-libudev-dev-wont-install-because-of-dependencies

`sudo apt-cache madison libudev-dev`

`sudo apt-cache madison libudev1`

`sudo apt-get install libudev-dev`

But I still get the same error. 
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling libudev1? Or are there other programs that will break if you remove it? It sounds like the program needs the EXACT version 229-4ubuntu4 (using =, not >=), so this might be a question for the developer of whichever program you are trying to install.

Comment: Using this code to check if other programs will break
`apt-cache rdepends libudev1`
it looks like there are a lot and im afraid to risk that if i uninstall/install libudev1 they might not be link together again.

okay it would be my last resort in contacting the developer

Comment: What application is this, as well? Someone else may have a similar problem with that package that might have been solved before.

Comment: You're sources are not updated & possibly xenial-updates repo is not enabled. Open Software & Updates > Updates tab > make sure that the 1st. two are enabled. (security & recommended updates) Then reload your source or go `sudo apt  update`. The current version for both packages is `229-4ubuntu6`

Comment: @doug thank you man. i really appreciated it. it is working now. im not sure how to give you credit. then again THANK YOU

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that there is a simple mix-up in the control file of that archive, you should report that as a bug.

However a actual workaround could be this very dirty hack, which can as well break things!

Download the package from [here](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libudev-dev_229-4ubuntu4_amd64.deb) then open a terminal and switch to your `Downloads` folder.

There unpack the `.deb` archive with:

```
dpkg-deb -R libudev-dev_229-4ubuntu4_amd64.deb tmp
```

Then change one line inside the `tmp/DEBIAN/control` file:

```
sed -i 's/229-4ubuntu4/229-4ubuntu5/' tmp/DEBIAN/control
```

After this repack the `.deb` file with (I choose here to give it a different name)

```
dpkg-deb -b tmp libudev-dev_229-fixbuntu_amd64.deb
```

Now you can install it after you made sure you have all dependencies installed already with:

```
dpkg -i libudev-dev_229-fixbuntu_amd64.deb
```

**Note:** This fix might work, but it can as well break things if there are really changes which are not taken into account properly by the maintainers. So understand you do this hack at your own risk.

Comment: This works, and probably won't have long-term consequences.  Searching for this particular error suggests that the maintainers of this particular package screw this up _a lot_, going back at least to 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

Try downgrading libudev1:

```
apt-get install libudev1=<version>
```

...to the version required by libudev-dev.

Then, it will remove lots of essential packages which you must reinstall manually.
For example,

```
sudo apt-get install libudev1=229-4ubuntu13
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:

The following packages will be REMOVED:
  alsa-base apparmor apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu bluez brltty checkbox-converged checkbox-gui click-apparmor console-setup console-setup-linux gdm3 gnome-bluetooth gnome-session gnome-session-bin
  gnome-session-wayland gnome-shell gnome-shell-extensions gnome-user-share gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse indicator-power indicator-sound initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-core kbd libcanberra-pulse
  lightdm linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic lvm2 media-player-info mountall nautilus network-manager network-manager-gnome plainbox-provider-checkbox
  plainbox-provider-resource-generic plymouth plymouth-label plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-x11 python3-apparmor-click
  python3-checkbox-support rhythmbox rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugins snapd software-properties-gtk ubuntu-drivers-common ubuntu-minimal udev udisks2 unity-greeter upower upstart usb-creator-common
  usb-creator-gtk xorg xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all
  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-vesa
  xserver-xorg-video-vmware
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  libudev1
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 downgraded, 80 to remove and 0 not upgraded.



for i in $(echo 'all removed packages above'); do apt-get install $i;done
```

Finally, you can install the libudev-dev which you want.

Answer (score 1):

As @doug said in a comment:

> You're sources are not updated & possibly xenial-updates repo is not enabled. 
>   GUI :: **Open Software & Updates > Updates tab >** make sure that the 1st. two are enabled. **(security & recommended updates)** Then **reload** your source 
>   **or**
>   CLI :: **sudo apt update**. The current version for both packages is 229-4ubuntu21.2 now.

in the view of CLI::
in /etc/apt/sources.list 
what will uncomment or adds? followings?

`deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security multiverse main universe restricted`