# Can't install libudev-dev on xUbuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, package-management, xubuntu, dependencies

This question is based on [Can't install libudev-dev on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779300/cant-install-libudev-dev-on-ubuntu-16-04) however updated for 20.04.

I cant seem to find a solution for installing libudev-dev package.
It outputs this error

> The following packages have unmet dependencies.
> libudev-dev : Depends: libudev1 (= 245.4-4ubuntu3.4) but 245.4-4ubuntu3.5 is to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

So i tried
sudo apt-get install libudev1

> libudev1 is already the newest version (245.4-4ubuntu3.5).

Ok... So I tried to downgrade libudev1

`apt install libudev1=245.4-4ubuntu3.4`

The list of packages to be removed was too long for comfort. It was 35 lines long.

I already looked at [Can't install libudev-dev on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779300/cant-install-libudev-dev-on-ubuntu-16-04) however, it's not obvious and it's for 2 LTS older versions than now.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: No. That is a different question. That one is about actual problems. In my case, it appears to be caused by bad version requirements by a package

Answer (score 0):

This answer was possible thanks to [Videonauth's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/779308/255736)

---

My guess is that there is a simple mix-up in the control file of that archive, you should report that as a bug.

However a actual workaround is a very dirty hack. Be careful, it may can as well break things!

Open a terminal. I recommend doing this in a dir inside shm for cleanness and speed:

```
mkdir /dev/shm/fixingudev
cd /dev/shm/fixingudev
```

Download the closest `libudev-dev_245.4` package from [here](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/). Make sure this is the closest version for your case to avoid incompatibilities! A difference after the dash shouldn't be much but if the sub-version is different, **stop and rethink this**.

```
wget "" -O "libudev-dev_before.deb"
// E.g. wget "https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libudev-dev_245.4-4ubuntu3.6_amd64.deb" -O "libudev-dev_before.deb"
```

There unpack the `.deb` archive with:

```
dpkg-deb -R libudev-dev_before.deb tmp
```

Then change one line inside the `tmp/DEBIAN/control` file:

```
sed -i 's/245.4-4ubuntu3.6/245.4-4ubuntu3.5/' tmp/DEBIAN/control
```

After this repack the `.deb` file with

```
dpkg-deb -b tmp libudev-dev_after.deb
```

Now you can install it after you made sure you have all dependencies installed already with:

```
dpkg -i libudev-dev_after.deb
```

**Warning:** This fix might work, but it can as well break things if there are changes which are not taken into account properly by the maintainers. So understand you do this hack at your own risk.