# How to install libudev on Jetson Xavier Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, dependencies, udev, arm64

I want to install `libudev` on Jetson Xavier, so when I try `sudo apt-get install libudev-dev` I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libudev-dev : Depends: libudev1 (= 245.4-4ubuntu3) but 245.4-4ubuntu3.19 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have seen a [solution for amd64](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1336082/cant-install-libudev-dev-on-xubuntu-20-04) but I don't know how to solve the problem for `arm64` as they don't provide a package for [arm64](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/). can you please tell me how can I solve this problem please? thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to apply all fixes; the package should be `libudev1 | 245.4-4ubuntu3.20 | focal-updates    | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` which you will note is available for *arm64*.   Are you using a Ubuntu system?  or the Nvidia product Jetson product which is a mixture of Ubuntu & Debian packages?

Comment: @guiverc `Jeston Linux Image`

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   Respins or Ubuntu based systems are not Ubuntu, and are off-topic here. You can use SE *Unix & Linux*